# Text area com imagem

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Olá, vou fazer um form e não sei como fazer para incluir uma imagem dentro da text área, algo desse tipo.

TEXTO
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

TEXTO

IMAGEM

TEXTO

Algo do tipo para o usuário incluir sabe? Como é feito aqui no stack overflow, para perguntas.

Comment: não entendi, teria um exemplo com imagem?

Comment: algo tipo como é aqui para perguntar.

Comment: Queria que o usuário pudesse incluir em qualquer lugar uma imagem, e pudesse logo após continuar escrevendo. Tipo, ele explica algo, e coloca uma imagem pra exemplificar, e continua escrevendo logo abaixo.

Comment: Uma opção é utilizar um editor do tipo WYSIWYG, como o [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com).

Comment: é isso ai que eu queria, muito obrigada!!!!

Comment: Você também poderia gostar de uma div contenteditable https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30279671/how-to-pass-an-image-into-a-html-textarea

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss, responde a pergunta com essa resposta.

Comment: Use o plugin de editor de texto CK editor.
http://ckeditor.com/

Comment: NicEdit: http://nicedit.com bem simples de usar, usei esse, atendeu minhas necessidades.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que você deseja fazer é resolvido com editores WYSIWYG (*What You See Is What You Get*). Um exemplo simples desses editores é o [TinyMCE](https://www.tinymce.com/). Para utilizá-lo:

1. Acesse a URL: https://store.ephox.com/signup/ para criar sua conta;
2. No menu lateral, acesse [API Key Manager](https://store.ephox.com/my-account/api-key-manager/);
3. Copie a chave que aparecer (irá utilizá-la mais tarde);

Para utilizá-lo na página, você pode fazer o download da biblioteca diretamente do site. Aqui utilizarei a versão na nuvem para fins de exemplo. Adicione o arquivo JavaScript `tinymce.min.js`, informando sua chave da API:

```
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=your_API_key"></script>
```

e crie o elemento `textarea` que deseja configurar como editor. Em seu arquivo JavaScript, adicione o trecho de código que inicializa o editor:

```
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
```

Sobre a utilização de imagens no editor, você pode ler a documentação [File & Image Upload](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/file-image-upload/).

Veja o exemplo abaixo (não funcional, pois está rodando no Snippet):

```js
tinymce.init({ selector:'textarea' });
```

```html
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js?apiKey=API_KEY"></script>

<textarea>Seu editor de texto</textarea>
```

---

Outros editores semelhantes:

- NicEdit: http://nicedit.com
- CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com
- YUI Rich Text Editor: https://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/editor/
- MarkItUp: http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/