# Input para criar "posts" em site de noticias

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, input, lavarel

Estou fazendo um projetinho pessoal de site de notícias usando Laravel e MySQL.

Quando um usuário fosse cadastrar uma notícia, eu queria que ele pudesse inserir parágrafos, negritos e outras formatações, da mesma forma que é possível quando vamos criar um tópico nesse fórum. Não sei nem por onde começar, alguém pode me ajudar?

Queria algo bem parecido com esse 'input' de criar tópico, pode ser até mais simples.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No meu banco eu criei a tabela 'posts' com os campos: `id(pk)`, `category_id(fk)`, `title`, `content(mediumtext)`, `thumbnail` (string que linka uma img) e `user_id`(fk do criador).

Comment: Você já tentou algo? Me parece ampla sua duvida da forma que está, se já tiver começado a elaborar algo, edite a pergunta e adicione, fica mais facil assim ja tendo um ponto de partida.

Comment: Duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/209622/5878

Comment: Você pode utilizar esse plugin: https://www.tinymce.com/ ele é bem fácil de usar e o melhor de tudo é gratuito.